# Git pull a specific tag itself?

Tags: debian, git, jenkins, jenkins-multibranch

Because Jenkins pulls a git repo without tags, I'd like to pull the specific tag I'm interested in.  Is there a syntax for this?

I'm aware of git syntaxes that pull *all* tags, and syntaxes that pull *from* tags.  What I'm after is the pulling of a single tag *itself*.

OS is a recent Debian.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need only the tag you can use `git fetch` instead, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54635270/1376969):

`git fetch origin tag V4.12.0.1 --no-tags`

`git fetch` looks more suitable for the task, since `git pull` aims to merge commits after the fetch.